# Dependencies in Xcode Workspaces

Tags: ios, xcode, workspace

I'm trying to set up a workspace so that different projects can access the same files.

In Project A, I did a "Save As Workspace..."

Then I created Project B in the new workspace.

I can now see both in the Project Navigator.

So say I have a category that was in Project A called "UIView+Awesome" that I want to use in Project B, how do I set up that dependency?

In a view controller of Project B I get this:

```
#import "UIView+Awesome.h" //UIView+Awesome.h file not found
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to solve it.

1. Click on the target that's importing `UIView+Awesome.h`.
2. Click on **Build Settings**.
3. Enter `Header Search Paths` into the search box.
4. Double click on the value cell.
5. Click the `+` sign.
6. Set the path to the project you're referring.  Let's say it's called `Awesomelib`.  The path is relative to the root of the referring project (the project that's using `Awesomelib`).  For example:  `../Awesomelib/src/headers/`  or wherever it is that the `.h` file lives.
7. Click `Done`.
8. `Clean` and then `Build`.

Comment: Thanks. This allowed me to compile. But when I run I get this: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[UIView someMethod:]: unrecognized selector sent to class

Comment: someMethod does exist, and is used by Project A.

Comment: This should be a separate question

Comment: I don't think it should be a separate question. It's still a dependency issue.